# C++ Shared Library does not export "extern C" functions

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, dllexport, extern-c

I'm working on a shared library and adding some functions which I export as c functions, so I can use them easily in C#. But none of my c functions are exported.

According to the app DependenciesGUI my c++ functions are exported, but none of my c functions.

I created a test class to demonstrate my problem:
TEST_API contains __declspec(dllimport) and export

```
#pragma once
#include "DLL_Macro.h"

class TEST_API Attempt {
    int x;
public:
    Attempt(int x);
    int adding(int y);
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void* Create(int x) {
    return (void*) new Attempt(x);
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int AttemptAdd(Attempt * a, int y) {
    return a->adding(y);
};
```

Comment: Please show a [mre] of both the DLL and the application using it.

Comment: This class should be enough on the c++ side. Except you want to see my cmake file. I can add a c# code but there is still the problem that the dll has no c functions.

Comment: @Tohrwarneth The class should be irrelevant to whether or not the function definitions cause functions to be emitted. Does just `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void* Create(int x) { return nullptr; }` also not result in any function with the symbol name `Create` or `_Create` in the dll according to the tool?

Comment: There is no Create function according to the tool. Only the cpp class and its functions.

Comment: You use the macro `TEST_API` for the class, which I assume is `__declspec(dllexport)` when building the DLL, and `__declspec(dllimport)` otherwise? Why don't you use the macro for the non-member functions as well? Right now you have hard-coded *export **only***. If you include this headerfile in the application using the DLL then it wont work.

Comment: What tool are you using to see whether an export exists?  Use the official tool `dumpbin /exports`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: C# can't include C headers in the first place, so there's no issue like "application trying to export a function that it should be importing".  In fact the DLL should NOT try to dllexport the class.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The hard-coded is only the what is behind my CTest_API Macro. I got it from a tutorial. So I changed Create only to your comment. And but both are now exported. And in other files there are compiler error, when I use TEST_API. It's the "// error C2491 : definition of dllimport function not allowed".

Comment: @BenVoigt It's a rework of the dependencies walker. https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

Comment: And now we need that [mre] of your code using the DLL. How do you "import" or declare those functions? What are the errors you get when you build or run the C# application? Also, include a screenshot of the application listing the exported functions, and tell us what file your looking at. If the output is text, then copy-paste it as text into the question instead.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and [ask]. Also please read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Also, are you including that header file in any source file used to build your DLL? To more than one source file? Into *no* source file? Are the function definitions only in a header file that is never included anywhere?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It was your guess with the include -.-
I reproduced it for the reproducible example. Thank you all <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution to the problem was simple:
include the header with the extern "C" functions in a source file. In my case in a cpp file of the class.

Comment: Alternative solution: Separate declaration and definition. Put the declaration in the header file, and the definition (implementation) in a source file.